# IProgressDialog not showing Marquee style

Tags: c#, winapi, progressdialog, marquee

I'm trying to use Win32 Shell's [IProgressDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-iprogressdialog-startprogressdialog) from C# using the flag `PROGDLG_MARQUEEPROGRESS`.

```
[ComImport]
[Guid("EBBC7C04-315E-11d2-B62F-006097DF5BD4")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IProgressDialog
{
    void StartProgressDialog(IntPtr hwndParent, object punkEnableModless, ProgressDialogFlags dwFlags, IntPtr pvResevered);

    void StopProgressDialog();

    void SetTitle(string title);

    void SetAnimation(IntPtr hInstAnimation, ushort idAnimation);

    [PreserveSig]
    bool HasUserCancelled();

    void SetProgress(uint dwCompleted, uint dwTotal);

    void SetProgress64(ulong ullCompleted, ulong ullTotal);

    void SetLine(uint dwLineNum, string pwzString, bool fCompactPath, IntPtr pvResevered);

    void SetCancelMsg(string pwzCancelMsg, object pvResevered);

    void Timer(TimerAction timerAction, object pvResevered);
}

[Flags]
public enum ProgressDialogFlags : uint
{
    Normal = 0,
    Modal = 1,
    AutoTime = 2,
    NoTime = 4,
    NoMinimize = 8,
    NoProgressBar = 16,
    Marquee = 32,
    NoCancel = 64
}

public void Main()
{
    var type = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("F8383852-FCD3-11d1-A6B9-006097DF5BD4"));
    var dialog = (IProgressDialog) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    dialog.StartProgressDialog(IntPtr.Zero, null, ProgressDialogFlags.Marquee, IntPtr.Zero);
    // ...
}
```

The dialog shows up but it doesn't show a marquee style progress bar animation.
It shows a default progress bar which does not advance.

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong here?

Regards
Christian

Comment: The marque works for me (Windows 10) when I run it as x64. It doesn't work when I run x86 for some reason.

Comment: `PROGDLG_MARQUEEPROGRESS` requires the Common Controls version 6. Have you verified that your application has an appropriate manifest for both 32-bit as well as 64-bit builds? See [Using Manifests or Directives to Ensure That Visual Styles Can Be Applied to Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview#using-manifests-or-directives-to-ensure-that-visual-styles-can-be-applied-to-applications) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Simon! That actually was the 'solution'. When I changed my test application to x64 it worked as expected. Don't know what the problem is when using x86 but I actually don't care as much as my "real life" application is 64 bit anyway.
I still don't know why 32 bit won't work but I actually don't need to care.